# Can IdentityServer3 allow Integrated Windows Authentication with ability to log in as different user

Tags: identityserver3

I'd like to know if its worth investing time into developing an IdentityServer3 implementation that would work similarly to  how Sharepoint allows for an initial Login using Integrated Windows Authentication, but then allow user to login as a different user with a prompt for credentials.  Our hospital has many users where their primary workstation is set up as generic login.  I'd like to use integrated Authentication, but allow these users on generic workstations to re-login as themselves.

From my research I think a logout page that actually invalidates the original token along with a secondary external Identity provider running without integrated Authentication is where I'm heading, but would like some validation that its feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You would approach that problem differently with IdentityServer - on the login page you would give the user a choice. Either use integrated authentication or specify some username/password explicitly.

Logging out of identityserver would then also allow to switch identity if needed.

So yes this is possible.

We have an example that does built-in Windows authN (username/password is disabled - but you can re-enable by setting EnableLocalLogin to true here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth%20All-in-One)/WebHost/Startup.cs#L36).

Comment: How would you then link the two accounts? How do you associate the Windows Auth user with the other user - they should be the same identity.